# How to add events for dynamically added single element which shares the class names in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, element, classname

In my use case, I am iterating through the list of objects and displaying in html with same set of class names for each object. If I click a button for an element the event should be triggered for that object not for every other elements which shares the same class name.

But the following code triggers for every element which shares the class name.

**HTML**

```
<div class="comment-list-new" style= "max-height: 660px !important;overflow-y: scroll;">
    <h5>Discussion Board</h5>
    <ol>
        {{  if .ViewData.Questions }}
        {{ range .ViewData.Questions }}
            <li>
                <div class="q-comment">
                    <div class="qanda questiondiv" id="questionarea" name="questionarea">
                        <div>
                            <div id="topic" class="upvote pull-left">
                                <a class="upvote"></a>
                                <span class="count">3</span>
                                <a class="downvote"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <div class="qanda-info">
                                    <h6><p id="quest_title">{{.QuestionTitle}}</p></h6>
                                </div>
                                <p id="quest_text">{{.QuestionText}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div >

                        <div class="qanda-info">
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <img src="/resources/img/team-small-2.png" />
                            </div>
                            <h6>{{.UserId}}</h6>
                            <span class="date alt-font sub">{{.DateCreated}}</span>
                            <a id="answertext" name ="answertext" type="submit" class="link-text answerbutton">Answer</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li><!--end of individual question-->
         {{ end }}
        {{ end }}

    </ol>
</div><!--end of comments list-->
```

**JS**

```
//Enables and disables the answer elements 
//for all questions
$('.answerbutton').on('click', function() {
    console.log("In submit answer text area");
    newdiv = "<div id='answersection' name='answersection' class='form-input answersectiondiv'><textarea name='answertextarea' id='answertextarea' rows='8' cols='85' placeholder='Answer description*''></textarea><br/><div class='form-input'><a type='Submit' id='submitanswer'  name='submitanswer' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit Answer</a><a type='Cancel' id='cancelanswer' name='cancelanswer' class='btn btn-primary cancelanswerbutton'>Cancel</a></div></div>";
    $('.questiondiv').append(newdiv);
    //$('.answerbutton').prop( 'disabled' , true );
    $('.cancelanswerbutton').on('click', function() {
        console.log("In cancel answer area");
        $('.answersectiondiv').remove();
    });
    //$('.answerbutton').prop( 'disabled' , false );
  });
```

Also I am not able to enable and disable[answerbutton - commented in code]. Could anyone help me with this? I am new to JQuery.

**EDIT-1**
Based on @Satpal suggestion I edited like this,

```
$('.questiondiv').on('click', '.answerbutton', function() {
    console.log("In submit answer text area");
    newdiv = "<div id='answersection' name='answersection' class='form-input answersectiondiv'><textarea name='answertextarea' id='answertextarea' rows='8' cols='85' placeholder='Answer description*''></textarea><br/><div class='form-input'><a type='Submit' id='submitanswer'  name='submitanswer' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit Answer</a><a type='Cancel' id='cancelanswer' name='cancelanswer' class='btn btn-primary cancelanswerbutton'>Cancel</a></div></div>";

    $(this).closest('.questiondiv').append(newdiv); //Again use this to remove only parent container div
});

$('.questiondiv').on('click', '.cancelanswerbutton', function() {
    console.log("In cancel answer area");
    $(this).closest('.answersectiondiv').remove(); //Again use this to remove only parent container div
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this`, it refers to element which invoked the event handler.

```
$('.answerbutton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prop( 'disabled' , false ); //Only commented code which needs to be updated added here
});
```

Additionally, You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically. Instead of of bind in the click handler.

```
//Enables and disables the answer elements 
//for all questions
$('.answerbutton').on('click', function() {
    console.log("In submit answer text area");
    newdiv = "<div id='answersection' name='answersection' class='form-input answersectiondiv'><textarea name='answertextarea' id='answertextarea' rows='8' cols='85' placeholder='Answer description*''></textarea><br/><div class='form-input'><a type='Submit' id='submitanswer'  name='submitanswer' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit Answer</a><a type='Cancel' id='cancelanswer' name='cancelanswer' class='btn btn-primary cancelanswerbutton'>Cancel</a></div></div>";
    $('.questiondiv').append(newdiv);
    $(this).prop( 'disabled' , false );
});
$('.questiondiv').on('click', '.cancelanswerbutton', function() {
    console.log("In cancel answer area");
    $(this).closest('.answersectiondiv').remove(); //Again use this to remove only parent container div
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The approach for dynamic elements worked. But for some reasons the disable answer button didn't work. I edited the question with your suggestion.

Comment: It worked with $('.answerbutton').prop( 'disabled' , true ); Since I am not in that element I couldn't use `(this)`. Otherwise `(this)` works well